# How to cut out unwanted content from the 3D model

Tags: mesh

Hi People hope everyone is good and having a good day, i am trying cut out a quater of a circle and i have tried using the knife tool but found this rather dificult and have tried the default editing tool and tried inverting the excess inwards but this did not work as well, as you can probably tell i ahve only just started learning how to do 3D modelling on blender. Basicly i just want to get rid of the excess quater i do not need. please see the PNG i have attached.
Any help would be apreciated.
Thank you :) 
P.S. i have done a landing foot and cut corners out thanks to bruno's instructions :) however i do it manualy for each corners and some corners as you can see from the picture are not equaly continuitive :)is there a way that i can duplicate the first cut like for like so all corners are the same :)[image]

Simon[image: Screen shot of blender project i need to cut]

Comment: maybe you wish to remove a quarter of the sphere-like big mesh as outlined in the picture? have you tried to select all the inner vertices and (eg) delete them? later you'll need to fill the hole though...

Comment: If you need to add more or different pictures edit *your own question* using the [edit] link, not someone elses answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it can save time to build the new geometry you need.

[image]

In this case:

1. Add a new UV sphere aligned to the world axes, with twice as many segments as rings. (Here, 32 and 16)
2. Delete the exterior faces over the section to be removed.
3. Put your snap settings to vertex, active, snap to self.
4. Extrude the vertex at the north pole downwards, constraining to Z, (**E,Z**) and snapping to a convenient vertex on the equator. This will create the edge from the north pole to the centre of the sphere.
5. Set 'Automatically merge vertices' on, and extrude the new central vertex outwards twice, once to each of the bottom corners of the removed section of the sphere. This will create the other two straight edges you can see.
6. Select all the new straight edges, and from the (**ctrl-E**) edges menu, select subdivide. At the bottom of the Tools panel, set the number of cuts to 3.
7. Fer each new flat face you are going to create, select the edges surrounding it, go to the face menu (**ctrl-F**) and select 'Grid Fill'. At the bottom of the tools panel, set the span to 4.
8. Bevel the edges of your new faces, if you want to.

It may all seem like a bit of a faff, but once you can find your way around, this sort of approach can take less time than tidying up after a Boolean. (I'm sure someone here will point out how I could have saved a few steps.)

Answer (score 2):

how about boolean modifier?

1. select your sphere
2. create and place a cube to remove part of the sphere
3. add the boolean/Difference modifier to the sphere and select the cube as the object to use for the operation
4. apply

[image]

Comment: Hiya Bruno thank you for your reply i am sure it is something i am doing wrong but i did follow your instructions and whne i clicked apply it cam,e up with the error message 'moddifier has been disabled'. Also i am trying to do slight indentations do you have any instructions ont hat to please?

Comment: Hi Bruno sorry about that it was me i missed out the part to switch it to cube in the object part. thank you. Would you be able to let me know about the indenting bit please.

Comment: :( ok i have tried the boolean on a different part of the model that i want the same effect on except with a sphere this time, however i still gt the error message that thge modifier is disabled again even though i do exactly how i did it before. :( can you offer any advise on what i am doing wrong? adding the sphere object dont seem to work.

Comment: Ok it lstarted to let me add the object the right one as i had sphere 1 to 9 listed however i still have an issue i click apply and it dont come up with the error message there is no spherical incut performed one i have taken the sphere out :( again i am new so i am sure it is me. :(

Comment: Are you using other modifiers like "Array" etc? If so, you have to apply them before doing the boolean otherwise the boolean op may not have a real mesh to work with...

Comment: Whats Array? as far as i know i am not using any other modifiers but as i am a total beginer i could have trigered one whilst getting myself used to and exploring this interface :) how would i know if i am using other modifiers?

Comment: I have put another picture up of what i want to do, you see the sphere at the back of the ship int he picture i want to use that the same way i used the cube to cut out 2 quaters of the sphere in my model as you can see in the picture above :)

Comment: I don't see any new pictures... that's all pretty confusing. You need to clarify better what you need by posting additional pictures, even doing some hand drawings if you can't find proper screenshots. As far as modifiers go, look in the Properties panel, there is a Modifiers subpanel. Also read the friendly manual on Modifiers: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/index.html

Comment: The new edit ( picture ) has not been verified on here yet that's probably why you cant see it. Yeah i found the problem the sphere i am using to make the indent is listed as sphere 15 but when i go into Boolean tool and try to select it it's not listed for some reason it jumps from sphere 14 to 16. I'l try deletiong the sphere 15 and create a new one and let you know what happens.

Comment: Can i apologise please :) after all this time i have found the issue, and it was me being an idiot, i had the UI in edit mode instead of object DOHHH lol :) thanks for your help mate much apreciated :)

Comment: Can you tell me once i have done the cutting of the object instead of me doing it manualy for each corner ( i am creating landing feet for my space craft ) is there a way i can keep continuity and be able to auto duplicate the exact cut for each corner so it is all contuity equal.

Comment: sorry but we are getting off topic here and you are really loosing me on the details!! Let's close the discussion!